# Export face groups as paths(vectors)

Tags: export

I need to export the colored face groups below as vectors so that I can import them into photoshop. 
My first approach was to use different colored shadeless materials which I could then turn into selections inside photoshop but it is not an accurate method, I have to have the vectors rendered inside photoshop.

[image: example]

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you want to project a 3D object into camera view and then export the face outlines as SVG?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a vectorizer, you may use Adobe Illustrator or InkScape for that. I don't think Blender's Freestyle feature supports this well. For simple models, it should be possible to write a script that turns the vertices and edges into 2d, but you need some 3D math and Blender Python experience.

Comment: maddin45: that is precisely what I am talking about

Comment: I don't think blender has native tools for that. You could maybe script your own tools in python, but you would have to deal with hidden faces and culling yourself. I think the easiest way is to use @CoDEmanX's approach: render the image in a high resolution and use a vectorizer.

Comment: Someone recently pointed me at this, but I haven't tried it yet, so I don't know if it's suitable. http://www.geocities.jp/blenderyard/freestyle/svgwriter_b26/README.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [addon](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?282824-SVG-output-script) which does this. It works on both meshes and curves, and has many options for coloring and shading.

Here's a setup which will output flat shaded faces with the diffuse color of your materials (click for larger image):

[image]

1. In cycles the viewport color is actually the diffuse color, which is used by the addon.
2. For flat shading be sure to turn off most of the effects and variations, as shown in the screenshot
3. Once everything is set, click export to export the viewport as a SVG.

The result is shown in inkscape on the left.